# LinearUpscale2DArrayInPlace in Unity Jobs

Tags: c#, unity3d

Well,

I have this function which is called in the Unity Job system, I'm profiling it:

[image: profile]

The code:

```
    public static void LinearUpscale2DArrayInPlace(NativeArray<double> array, int width, int height, int anchorStepX, int anchorStepY, int min = 0, int max = 0)
    {
        // Interpolate columns where the anchor points are
        var lastYCell = height - anchorStepY;
        for (var y = min; y < lastYCell + max; y += anchorStepY)
        {
            for (var x = min; x < width + max; x += anchorStepX)
            {
                var index0 = To2D1D(y, x, width);
                var index1 = To2D1D(y + anchorStepY, x, width);

                if (!IsInBounds(index0, min, max) || !IsInBounds(index1, min, max))
                    continue;

                var startValue = array[index0];
                var endValue = array[index1];
                var diff = endValue - startValue;

                for (var cellY = 1; cellY < anchorStepY; cellY++)
                {
                    var index2 = To2D1D(y + cellY, x, width);
                    if (!IsInBounds(index2, min, max))
                        continue;
                    array[index2] = startValue + diff * cellY / anchorStepY;
                }
            }
        }

        // Interpolate in rows, each row has values in the anchor columns
        var lastXCell = width - anchorStepX;
        for (var y = min; y < height + max; y++)
        {
            for (var x = min; x < lastXCell + max; x += anchorStepX)
            {
                var index0 = To2D1D(y, x, width);
                var index1 = To2D1D(y, x + anchorStepX, width);

                if (!IsInBounds(index0, min, max) || !IsInBounds(index1, min, max))
                    continue;

                var startValue = array[index0];
                var endValue = array[index1];
                var diff = endValue - startValue;

                for (var cellX = 1; cellX < anchorStepX; cellX++)
                {
                    var index2 = To2D1D(y, x + cellX, width);
                    if (!IsInBounds(index2, min, max))
                        continue;
                    array[index2] = startValue + cellX * diff / anchorStepX;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool IsInBounds(int v, int min, int max) =>
        v >= min && v < max;

    public static bool IsInBounds(int v, int length) =>
        v >= 0 && v < length;

    public static int To2D1D(int x, int y, int width) =>
        x + y * width;
```

I'm unsure what can I do to improve those methods. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 3):

Yay, a performance question that comes with profiler measurements! Excellent.

## function call overhead

Thank you for those three tiny helper functions,
they do a good job of explaining what's going on.

However, maybe we'd like to inline them?
I mean, with your current optimization flags, maybe the compiler cannot "see through" the
function call boundary, so it's having a tough time
proving some very basic arithmetic facts?

Which leads us to...

## 1-D versus 2-D

Passing in a one-dimensional array
seems like a pretty inconvenient way of
representing your higher level business concepts.
Couldn't we cast it to a two-dimensional array?
I'd even be willing to suffer the cost of a
single big `memcpy()`if it meant the compiler
could easily see that (x, y) remain within bounds.

I know `/` division isn't *quite* as expensive
as it used to be on earlier CPUs.
But still, that `cellY / anchorStepY` expression
to recover a y-coordinate seems inconvenient.
I'm sad that in that loop we don't have row number
already available for use.
(Or perhaps you've arranged for `anchorStepY` to be a power-of-two,
leading to simple bit shifting.)

## in-bounds by construction

```
                if (!IsInBounds(index0, min, max) || ... )
                    continue;
```

Does this even trigger, does it ever report out-of-bounds?
The `y < lastYCell + max`
and `x < width + max`
guards seem like they're *already* performing the same work, no?
If that predicate *does* sometimes report `false`,
then consider changing the loop around, not unlike a loop unroll.
Maybe you'd like to iterate over slightly fewer cells with **no** check,
and then at the end take care of those remaining cells while carefully checking.

I wonder if a few judicious assert statements
would help the compiler to see that indexes
are provably within-bounds.
Comparing generated object code
for very slightly different functions
over at https://godbolt.org may prove instructive.

---

This code achieves most of its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: (Or perhaps you've arranged for anchorStepY to be a power-of-two, leading to simple bit shifting) AnchorStep param is power of two, 4, 8, 16... Also, In-bounds is triggered because I'm using Unity IParallelForBatch and the script can be outside of the split array formed by Unity Jobs. Also, I cannot use 2D arrays in Unity Jobs...

Comment: Ok, so you're working within constraints, I understand. But _after_ unity hands you a 1D array, you could still turn it into 2D, right? Even if it costs a single memcpy() ? Might be worth a benchmark bake-off to see if it's winning. And as far as parallel goes, maybe the cure is worse than the original slowness symptom? Maybe stick to one thread? Or break out the bulk of the work in parallel jobs that are "easy", and leaving a few "hard" cases for the final thread?

Comment: No... Unity doesn't allow 2D arrays, NativeArrays are 1D only :( In the parallel case, I only want to test parallel jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The best optimization is to remove computations that aren't required entirely. Since there is a direct mathematical relationship between the loop variables and the index variables it should be possible to remove the bounds check completely by simply adjusting the loop boundaries accordingly.

So let's look at `index0` and `index1` first.

We know:

1. Both `x` and `y` always start at `min`.
2. `index0 = y + x * width` and `index1 = y + stepY + x*width`

What I assume:

1. You never exceed `2^31` for `x` and `y` (i.e. no overflow)
2. `width >= 1`
3. `stepY >= 1`

From this we can conclude:

1. The bounds check for `<= min` is pointless since we know that `index0` and `index1` are by necessity greater than `min`
2. For any `x > max/width` both `index0` and `index1` will be greater than `max` too and thus be out of bounds.
3. For any `y > max - stepY` `index1` will be greater than `max` and thus out of bounds
4. For any given value of `y` if `x > max/width - y` then `index0` will be out of bounds

This means the first two loops can have adjusted boundaries without changing any other logic:

```
for (var y = min; y <= max - anchorStepY; y += anchorStepY)
{
    for (var x = min; x <= max/width - y; x += anchorStepX)
    {
```

Given the above - for `index2` we know that

1. `index2 = y + cellY + x * width` with `cellY = [1, stepY]`
2. We also know that `y <= max - stepY` which means that `max(index2) = max - stepY + stepY + x * width`

From this we can conclude that the bounds check is not required and can be removed.

Last but not least:

1. `index1 = index0 + stepY` - this removes one `To2D1D` call
2. `index2 = index0 + cellY` - this removes another `To2D1D` call

Furthermore you can introduce a loop variable for `index0` which gets initialized to `y` and gets incremented by `width` on every iteration of `x`. Something like this:

```
for (var y = min; y <= max - anchorStepY; y += anchorStepY)
{
    var index0 = y;
    for (var x = min; x <= max/width - y; x += anchorStepX, index0 += width)
    {
```

Now we have eliminated all calls to `To2D1D`

Similar logic can be applied to the second loop block.

At this point none of the helper methods are required any longer.